# CKEditor toolbar missing when conditional field becomes visible

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, toolbar

I use the D8 Conditional Fields module to make a CKEditor field (author bio) invisible until there is something in another field (author). When I type something in the author field, the author bio field becomes visible, but it doesn't include a CKEditor toolbar. It appears that CKEditor initialization is not done on fields that aren't initially visible. Any way to overcome this?

Comment: Yes but it the answer will require 1) removing the Conditional filed rule 2) adding a custom module that will attach custom js to your form the js will just hide the field on page load and then check the value of author field. thoughts ?

Comment: Thanks, @TaggartJensen. I was (still am) hoping someone will say, "Oh yeah, there's this setting in CKE to tell it to initialize non-visible fields." Failing that, I may try what you suggest, but I'll try the js injector to add js to the page without a custom module.

Comment: As an updated, I took @Taggart Jensen'suggestion and used a bit of injected Javascript to show/hide the author bio field. I'll add an answer with the code, in case it's helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not finding a built-in way to avoid the problem of missing CKEditor toolbars on conditionally displayed fields, instead of using the Conditional Fields module, I use the Asset Injector module's JS Injector to inject this JavaScript into the node add/edit page (note that the authors field is an entity reference):

```
var el = document.getElementById("edit-field-authors-0-target-id");

if (el) {
  showHideBio();
  el.addEventListener("change", showHideBio);
}

function showHideBio()
{
  var el = document.getElementById("edit-field-bio-wrapper");

  if (this.value) {
    el.style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    el.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Seems to work just fine, but open to suggestions for improvement. Thanks to @Taggart Jensen for the idea.